# Default audio player won't update?

Tags: javascript, html

So my audio player progressbar stays at 0, and the lenght of the songs is displayed at 0:00 as well if i use javascript to manipulate songs. How can i make the progressbar update itself and the lenght of the song playing to be shown correctly.

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="windows-1250">
<title>Aljaževa stran</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stil.css">
<script>
    var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    function init(){
        audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'Rhythm_is_a_dancer.ogg');
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <audio controls="controls"></audio>
</body>
</html>
```

Halfway through the song -> 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the `audio` tag an id and do this:

```
var audioElement = document.getElementById('audio');
```

instead of this:

```
var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
```

Instead of creating a new element you need to target the one you already have in the markup.

Comment: But my song doesnt play if i do that.

Comment: The `audioElement = document.getElementById('audio');` needs to be set within the `init()` function otherwise the element doesn't exist at the time that line is executed.